# Creating a dummy rails app with bundler for gem development?

Tags: ruby, testing, rubygems, bundler

I'm using bundler for gem development, now I need a dummy rails app (usually in the test folder) for testing, there is a way to create a dummy rails app with bundler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create it with the usual `rails new` command.